# Change CSS3 animation-duration with a transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I try to reduce the animation duration like this.

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#platines .disc {
  background: url(../img/disc.png) no-repeat;
  height: 86px;
  width: 86px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation-name:             rotate; 
  -webkit-animation-duration:         0.9s; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:  linear;
}

#platines .disc.paused {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-animation-duration 2s;
  -webkit-animation-duration:  60s; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:  4;
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Do you already found a solution around this problem?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It works for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/ZScuH/ (I speeded the animation up so that it's bearable to watch!). It doesn't work in Firefox as you've used the -`webkit-` prefix...

Comment: Initially, `.disc` rotates faster then `.paused` is added to slow down the animation with a transition (`-webkit-transition: -webkit-animation-duration 2s;`). This does not work.

Comment: As you can see : http://jsfiddle.net/c9Vyw/. When the background color turns yellow, the rotation should slow down and stop. It's at least what I try to do.

Comment: Works for me, you just have to wait a while for the 4 rotations to happen.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's impossible.
Animation-duration is not animatable.

[source on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-duration)

If you change this value when the animation is running, it will restart the animation without transitions.